# QTableWidget - combobox delegate how do I allow different options per cell

Tags: c++, qt, qtablewidget, qcombobox, qitemdelegate

Aloha

I have a QTableWidget with two columns that are currently using a ComboboxDelegate (my subclass of QItemDelegate) to present options to the user. I'd like the choice in the first column to effect the options available in the second, for the current row only.

E.g have a list of cars in the first column, and in the second a list of colours which are available for that car. Other rows to have different cars selected and thus different colour choices available.

From what I can see, I can only set an item delegate per row or column, so I can't see how to change the options in the second column's delegate without affecting all the other rows.

Is this possible? I'd really like to avoid going to a full view/model separation as I have quite a bit of code looking at this QTableWidget already (and I'm under time pressure)

Answer (score 0):

Well for those interested; I went back to my pre-delegate approach, which was to use QTableWidget::setItemWidget() to provide a combobox widget for each cell.

I subclassed qcombobox to take a reference to the table, and connected the combobox CurrentIndexChanged with a slot to update the table data. 
(setting a widget in a cell does not affect the tablewidget data unless you do this).

Using a full combobox like this is more expensive than an itemdelegate, but my tables are very small so I can get away with it. The rendering of the combobox is not as nice as the delegate (the combobox is visible all the time instead of only during editing in the delegate's case), but with time I'm sure I can improve on this.